# how to set default web browser for web application

Tags: eclipse

I am using web app preview to test my website.  It is loading in Eclipse internal browser then I am copying that link and loading in Chrome browser.

How can I run  it directly in Chrome browser? (My default browser is Chrome.)

Answer (score 7):

You can change it by navigate to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser, change the Radio button to **Use external web browser** and select your browser on list in eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Go to your eclipse Window -> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser 
and you can select your default Web Browser here and if you want to add some other web browser then click on New button and put  and  and then click on OK and then after your can see your newly added browser in "External web browser" section. and select your favorite browser.[image]